# How to add x amount of words of x length to different nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a piece of work which requires me to add words to there corresponding list depending on the length of the word. I.e all words of length 1 will go in list 1, length 2 will go in list 2, etc...

Below is the code I currently have. As you can see I've created a list with L empty buckets and the idea is to have each length word to go in there corresponding bucket. This is where I am stuck. Without knowing how many buckets there are going to be, I don't know how to add them.
I am very new to Python and any help would be much appreciated!!

```
def empty_buckets(n): 
    """Return a list with n empty lists. Assume n is a positive integer. """ 
    buckets = [] 
    for bucket in range(n): 
        buckets.append([]) 
    return buckets
```

## Compute the maximum length L of all words.

```
longest = ''
    for L in words:
        if len(L) > len(longest):
            longest = L
    return longest
```

## Create a list of L empty lists (buckets).

```
buckets = empty_buckets(L)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [mcve]. What is `empty_buckets(L)`? Where is your list? Examples with expected input and output are helpful. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Apologies, I missed off the first part;

def empty_buckets(n):
    """Return a list with n empty lists.
    
    Assume n is a positive integer.
    """
    buckets = []
    for bucket in range(n):
        buckets.append([])
    return buckets

Comment: @S.Lowe edit your post to include this code.

Comment: Using **dictionary** would be a nice solution for this.

Comment: Now, I did that using **dictionary**. So for input words `["a",  "git", "go", "py", "", "java", "paper", "ruby", "r","TheIpMan", ""]` the output would be `[['', ''], ['a', 'r'], ['go', 'py'], ['git'], ['java', 'ruby'], ['paper'], [], [], ['TheIpMan']]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the longest word in a list of words with `max()` and supplying a key-function of `len`.

You can create one more bucket for "empty" words and sort all your words into the buckets using a for loop and indexing into your buckets with `len(word)`:

```
# create some demo strings and add some other words
words = [ str(10**k) for k in range(10)]
words.extend(["this","should","work","out","somehow"])

print(words)  # ['1', '10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000', '1000000', '10000000',
              #  '100000000', '1000000000', 'this', 'should', 'work', 'out', 'somehow']

longest = len(max(words,key=len)) # get the length of the longest word

# create a empty bucket for "" and one bucket for length 1 up to longest
bins = [None] + [ [] for _ in range(longest+1)]  

# loop over words and put then in the bin at index len(word)
for w in words:
    bins[len(w)].append(w)

print(bins)
```

Output:

```
[None, ['1'], ['10'], ['100', 'out'], ['1000', 'this', 'work'], ['10000'], 
       ['100000', 'should'], ['1000000', 'somehow'], ['10000000'], 
       ['100000000'], ['1000000000']]
```

Doku:

- [max(iterable, key=len)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)
- [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)
- [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Answer (score 0):

`buckets = [0] * longest # this will make a list of longest size`

Then, make a list within each element and I am using the first element of the list to keep a count of that bucket.

`for i in range(longest):
       buckets[i] = [0]`

Then you need to add the words to the buckets.

`for L in words:
      buckets[len(L)][0] += 1 # increasing the count of that bucket
      buckets[len(L)].append(L) # Adding the word to that bucket`

Here is an example:

```
longest = 10
words = ['this', 'that', 'foremost']
buckets = [0] * longest # this will make a list of longest size 
for i in range(longest):
   buckets[i] = [0]
for L in words:
   buckets[len(L)][0] += 1 # increasing the count of that bucket
   buckets[len(L)].append(L) # Adding the word to that bucket
```

To access any of the counts, it is just `buckets[number][0]` and to access all the words, you loop that count starting with `buckets[number][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

As I had mentioned in comment before, I used dictionary to solve this problem.

Here, you do not need to bother about creating empty list using any external function as we do not know the actual length.

So you can try like this.

> You can visit https://rextester.com/ZQKA28350 to run the code online.

```
def add_words_to_bucket(words): 
    d = {}

    for word in words: 
        l = len(word)
        if l in d: 
            d[l].append(word) 
        else: 
            i = 0
            while l >= 0 and not l in d:
                if not i: 
                    d[l] = [word]
                else: 
                    d[l] = []
                l = l - 1
                i += 1
    return d

def get_as_list(d): 
    bucket = [d[i] for i in range(0, len(d))]
    return bucket


words = ["a",  "git", "go", "py", "java", "paper", "ruby", "r"]
d = add_words_to_bucket(words) 
bucket = get_as_list(d)
print(d) # {0: [], 1: ['a', 'r'], 2: ['go', 'py'], 3: ['git'], 4: ['java', 'ruby'], 5: ['paper']}
print(bucket) # [[], ['a', 'r'], ['go', 'py'], ['git'], ['java', 'ruby'], ['paper']]


words2 = ["a",  "git", "go", "py", "", "java", "paper", "ruby", "r","TheIpMan", ""]
d2 = add_words_to_bucket(words2)
bucket2 = get_as_list(d2)
print(d2) # {0: ['', ''], 1: ['a', 'r'], 2: ['go', 'py'], 3: ['git'], 4: ['java', 'ruby'], 5: ['paper'], 6: [], 7: [], 8: ['TheIpMan']}
print(bucket2) # [['', ''], ['a', 'r'], ['go', 'py'], ['git'], ['java', 'ruby'], ['paper'], [], [], ['TheIpMan']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def bucket_words_by_length(words):
    d = {}
    [d.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word) for word in words]
    buckets = [d.get(k, []) for k in range(max(d.keys()) + 1)]
    return buckets
```

For example,

```
>>>words = ['hi', 'my', 'friend', 'how', 'are', 'you']
>>>bucket_words_by_length(words)
[[], [], ['my', 'hi'], ['you', 'how', 'are'], [], [], ['friend']]
```

This implementation first builds a dictionary with lengths as its keys and a list of the words of corresponding length as its values. Next, it iterates through all of the lengths producing an empty list if no words are of that length and producing the list of words otherwise.